# Merge segfaults after running for several times C++(pointer arithmetic)

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to implement merge sort where, instead of making smaller temp arrays to merge, I just use pointer arithmetic to "partition" the sub arrays. I've been staring at this for a few days now and I cannot figure out where I've gone wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
template <typename T>
void sorts<T>::merge(T* a1, T* a2, int size1, int size2)
{
//create buffer array
T* temp = new T[size1+size2];
int x = 0;//index a1
int y = 0;//index a2
int z = 0;//index buffer
//merge into buffer
while(x<size1&&y<size2)
{
    if(a1[x]<a2[y])
    {
        temp[z] = a1[x];
        z++;
        x++;
    }
    else
    {
        temp[z] = a2[y];
        z++;
        y++;
    }
}
//Copy the remaining elements of a1
while(x<size1)
{
    temp[z] = a1[x];
    z++;
    x++;
}
//Copy the remaining elements of a2
while(y<size2)
{
    temp[z] = a2[y];
    z++;
    y++;
}
//write buffer back
z = 0;
while(z<size1+size2)
{
    a1[z] = temp[z];
    z++;
}
delete temp;
}
template <typename T>
void sorts<T>::mergeSort(T arr[], int size)
{
    if(size>1)
    {
    if(size%2==1)//odd
    {
        int x = (size-1)/2;
        mergeSort(arr,x);
        mergeSort(arr+x+1,size-x);
        merge(arr, arr+x+1, x, size-x);
    }
    else//even
    {
        int x = (size)/2;
        mergeSort(arr,x);
        mergeSort(arr+x+1,size-x);
        merge(arr, arr+x+1, x, size-x);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your debugger say is happening?

Comment: You should insert in the question the problem you are having and possibly an expected result. Have a look at [ask]

Comment: Wot no `delete`? `T` might be come back as `nullptr` as you steafily obliterate your memory. But most likely it's an out of bounds array access. Time to get that debugger out.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with the code.

When you delete your temporary array in `merge`, you aren't using the correct form of `delete`.  Since `temp` was allocated with `new T[]`, you need to delete it as an array with `delete [] temp;`.

The more serious problem is the out-of-bounds accesses you do.  When you call `mergeSort(arr+x+1,size-x)` you skip element `arr[x]`, and try to access element `arr[size]`, which is (possibly) past the end of whatever memory was allocated for `arr`.  You should be using `arr+x` for your first parameter (with the same adjustment when calling `merge` after sorting).

There's no difference between your "odd" and "even" sections in `mergeSort`, since an odd number divided by 2 will truncate, resulting in the same value you get when subtracting one before doing the division.